# How to disable actions while UIWebView loads?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uialertview

I created the following code to check whether there's an internet connection or not when a page is loading. If there isn't; a message will pop up. If there is, nothing pops up.
The problem I am having is that when there's an internet connection and the UIWebView is loading and at the same time I press other buttons like back or forward, the message of No Internet Connection pops up! Any idea how could I avoid this? Is there a way to disable other actions while my UIWebView loads?

Code:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)NBC didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{ 
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection" 
                      message:@"Please verify your connection" 
                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                      otherButtonTitles:/*@"Verify", */nil];
    [alert show]; 
    [alert release]; 
}
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [buttonForward setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [buttonForward setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let's say the IBAction for the forward button is: 

<blink> 




-(IBAction)GoForward:(id)sender{

 [TheWebView goForward];

 
}

</blink>

The produced code should be :

<code>

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)TheWebView{
 
[GoForward setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}

</code>

Though I am getting this error: GoForward undecleared.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, yeah, you have to define your buttons in the .h file and link them to your buttons in the XIB file and then replace GoForward with the forward button name and then duplicate the line and add the go back button's name. Also, if my answer is right, could you please mark it as so? Thanks!

Comment: I defined it in the .h as : @ property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton*GoForward;  and then synthesized it: @synthesize GoForward; It doesn't give me any errors while compiling but still I have the same problem as before (The problem I posted about)

Comment: Jack, it worked! I was connecting the IBActions but forgot about the IBOutlets. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code,

```
   [self.webView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

This may help you.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of blocking user interface, unless it's critical. Why not just check for the right type of error, and then decide to show the alert to the user?

My bet is that clicking on another thing is making the UIWebView abort with some `NSError` like `NSURLErrorCancelled`, which is triggering your Alert code.

[Here's a list of the foundation errors](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793).

Comment: Hi, Actually i'm not blocking any user interface. I'm quite new to iOS programming but my intention if I had to say it in C# words it would be:

if
(webBrowse.IsBusy)
{ btnForward.Enabled = false;
btnRefresh.Enabled = true; }
else
{ btnRefresh.Enabled = true; }
btnStop.Enabled = false;}

This is what I would like to get...